# Try/catch function only runs once even with a while loop C#

Tags: c#, loops, exception, while-loop, try-catch

I am trying to create a command-line application that searches through a directory of song names and albums input by the user and then plays that song. When the user inputs a non-existing song name or album, the program throws a `DriectoryNotFoundException`.

I have put the "song grabber" function within the try block and then if a user inputs an invalid directory, it goes to the catch block and tries again. It works as intended, yet only once. I have tried putting a while loop to make sure the try/catch function keeps working until the program fully succeeds.

```cs
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        MusicSelector.SongGrabber();
        break;
    }
    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the exact song names and album.");
        MusicSelector.SongGrabber();
    }
}
```

What should I do in order to retry until the user inputs a valid directory?

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't be using a try catch as your primary flow control. You would instead check for the directory with one of the Exist methods, then fall back to exception handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user does it wrong the second time, the call of `MusicSelector.SongGrabber()` in the `catch` block will throw another exception which isn't catched and ends the program.

So don't call `MusicSelector.SongGrabber()` in the `catch` block again. Do nothing in the `catch` block, or even better print a message to inform the user of what went wrong. The loop will be iterated again and the call of `MusicSelector.SongGrabber()` will be done again in the `try` block so that the `catch` block can catch a new exception should one be thrown.

And it would certainly be nice to give the user the instructions before, so that they know what they're supposed to do. I.e. you may also want to consider to move the `Console.WriteLine()`.

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the exact song names and album.");
        MusicSelector.SongGrabber();
        break;
    }
    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The directory wasn't found.");
    }
}
```

And `try`-`catch` isn't a function but a statement.

Answer (score 1):

You `break` out of the loop after a successful invocation of `SongGrabber`. Remove that `break` and the call from the `catch` (since you have one in the `try` block and the loop will ensure you revisit it) and you should be OK:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        MusicSelector.SongGrabber();
        // break removed here
    }
    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the exact song names and album.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your description, I see that you are trying to fix something with a workaround(try-catch) instead of actually tackling the issue.

You know that the user can fill in an incorrect path so you need to check on that and then start the search if it's correct or stop the code and give the user feedback that the path is incorrect.

I'm not exactly sure how you build your code but here is how I would do it.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the exact song names and album.");
var path = path.Trim(); //This is the parameter of the user sending the path

//If directory does not exist, don't even try. Give feedback and stop
if (!Directory.Exists(path))  
{  
    //In case they cannot start it again then call the method on how to ask the path in here
    Console.WriteLine("Path is invalid, try again");
    return;
}

//try to get the song
var song = MusicSelector.SongGrabber(); //I assume you should pass the path here as a parameter.

//No song was found
if(song == null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("There was no song found");
   return;
}

//Song was found. Do something with it like play the song :)
MusicPlayer.Play(song);
```

Comment: You still need to Try/Catch. The directory could be removed after the Exists check and before the next line. There's always going to be a race condition, but one shouldn't rely *soley* on exceptions for flow control